# How to handle error when submitting data in flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

When submitting data troughs user input and the data  doesn't match anything in mongodb collections  the Jinja template throw an error (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable) but when data is existing in the collection the data loads to the template without any problem and i don't know how to handle this error.
And as well how i can refresh the page After the submit because the results from search input doesn't disappear after reloading the page.
Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

this is my Python code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import (
    Flask, flash, render_template,
    redirect, request, session, url_for)
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
if os.path.exists("env.py"):
    import env


app = Flask(__name__)


app.config["MONGO_DBNAME"] = os.environ.get("MONGO_DBNAME")
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = os.environ.get("MONGO_URI")
app.secret_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")


mongo = PyMongo(app)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route("/search", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search():
    query = request.form.get("company-name")
    company = mongo.db.company.find_one(
        {"company_name": query})["company_name"]
    if company:
        review = list(mongo.db.review.find({"company_name": company}))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    return render_template("home.html", review=review)
```

html Jinja tempalte

```
    <form class="serach-form" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
        <label class="search-bar-label" name="company-name" for="company- 
              name">Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="company-name" name="company-name">
            <button class="serch-button btn light-blue accent-4" type="submit" 
              name="action"><span>Search</span>
                <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt sign-in-icon"></i><i class="fas fa- 
              search search-icon"></i>
            </button>
    </form>

<div>
    {% if review|length > 0 %}
        {% for set in review %}
            <strong>{{ set.company_name }}</strong> <br>
            <strong>{{ set.username }}</strong><br>
            <strong>{{ set.score }}</strong><br>
            <strong>{{ set.review_content }}</strong><br>           
        {% endfor %} 
    {% else %}
        <h3 class="red-text text-darken-4 center-align">No Results Found</h3>
    {% endif %}       
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but still, I have no idea what was wrong with the code I wrote.

python code

```
@app.route("/search", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search():
    query = request.form.get("company-name")
    review = list(mongo.db.review.find(
        {"company_name": query}))
    return render_template("home.html", query=query, review=review)


html :
<div id="review-search">
{% if review|length > 0 %}
<h2 class="black-text text-darken-4 center-align review-search- 
     heading">Results for  <span class="found"> {{ query }} </span> 
</h2>
<h3> total {{ total_score }}</h3>

    {% for set in review %}
    <div class="row top-margin hot-company">
        <div class="col m8 s10 offset-m2 offset-s1 grey lighten-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s10 offset-s1 blue-text">
                    <h5>{{ set.username }}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s10 offset-s1 red-text">
                    <p>{{ set.score }}/10</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s10 offset-s1">
                    <p>{{ set.review_content }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>     
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <h2 class="red-text text-darken-4 center-align review-search- 
         heading">No Results Found for   <span> "{{ query }}"</span> 
    </h2>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

use

```
try:
  // task1
except:
  // executed when there's runtime error while doing task1
```

Comment: thanks apridos much appreciate your help.